# WatchKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, watchkit, simulator, xcode11.4

I want to run app that have watch target but when try to build on xCode 11.4 This error is raised
"WatchKit is not available when building for iOS Simulator."

Comment: What simulator have you selected as your execution target?  You need to select a simulator that you have paired with a simulated watch.

Comment: @Paulw11
i just want to run app not watch app but error is still shown !

"ld: framework not found WatchKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the iOS app target, not the watch target. Also, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494422/xcode-11-beta-wont-build-because-of-watchkit) helps